# Add python datetime hours

Tags: python, datetime

I have a date and time data set (spanning roughly a year and a half) and I have converted this information into a python datetime object and plotted this on the x-axis (in months) versus some dependent data on the y-axis. My question involves taking the datetime data and converting this to cumulative hours, ie rather than plotting april, may, june, july, etc I want to take that datetime information and plot the associated hour number which will add as the months go forward on the x-axis (ie 0, 100, 200, 300, etc). I suppose I am looking for suggestions on pseudo-code as to how I might increment each hour in the time series after the first 12 hours, any and all help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: if you add some of the relevant code it would help your cause

Comment: So, you want the x-axis to show number of hours from some reference datatime, correct?

Comment: Correct, I want the x-axis showing hour number from the original date and time.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform arrhythmic with `datetime.datetime` instances.  If you subtract one `datetime.datetime` instance from another, you will get a `datetime.timedelta` object.  You can then use the resulting time differences as your axis labels.  You can get the total number of seconds via `datetime.timedelta.total_seconds()` and convert that to hours.

Comment: `delta.total_seconds()` converts delta to seconds, not hours.  To convert to hours - use the division operator: `delta / timedelta(hours=1)`.

Comment: Yep, I state that it converts to seconds, but your conversion to hours with `timedelta` is a good touch.  ***wow, I saw your that after two minutes?